# Are Hanson and Penhall confirmed dead?

Tags: character, 21-jump-street

The movie remake of *21 Jump Street* is  comedy that suspends reality quite a bit in some cases. So even though the character played by Johnny Depp and Peter Deluise seemed to receive fatal wounds is it confirmed that they were KIA? I'm asking because they appeared as their original characters and since there is a sequel planned (and maybe another after that) if they are not KIA I figure there is a chance they may show up or be mentioned at some point. Also in universe I can't imagine the death of two DEA agents could be part of a successful take down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No** - if you want to be *exacting* about it.

They appeared in 21 Jump Street in tribute to the characters they played on the original TV series the movie was based on.

We never see them actually *die* and 22 Jump Street makes *zero* mention of them or their futures. It is *likely* they are dead given the wounds they received, but they are not *confirmed* dead at any point in the movie (or, to the best of my knowledge, by any director interview).

Comment: It's not quite about being *exacting* but just whether there is a chance for future cameos. Also in universe losing two officers would be looked down on. Also they were talking quite a bit after receiving their wounds.

Answer (score 0):

Their roles are no more than homage to the [21 Jump Street (TV series)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21_Jump_Street). So, they are most probably dead and are not even listed in the [22 Jump Street cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_Jump_Street).

The similar kind of cameos from TV series are expected in the sequel too, even mentioned in [cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_Jump_Street#Cast).